# proof of inequality $e^x\le x+e^{x^2}$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

Does anybody have a simple proof this inequality 
$$e^x\le x+e^{x^2}.$$

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456940/proof-of-the-inequality-ex-le-ex2-x and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781658/the-proof-of-ex-leq-x-ex2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For $x \geq 0$,
$$
e^{x^2 - x} + x e^{-x} \geq 1 + (x^2 - x) + x (1-x) = 1 \> .
$$

For $x < 0$, let $y = - x > 0$, whence,
$$
e^{-x^2}(e^x - x) = e^{-y^2} (e^{-y} + y) \leq e^{-y^2} (1 - y + y^2/2 + y) \leq e^{-y^2}(1+y^2) \leq e^{-y^2} e^{y^2} = 1 \> .
$$

---

Notice that we've only used the basic facts that $e^x \geq 1 + x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $e^{-x} \leq 1 - x + x^2/2$ for $x \geq 0$, both of which are trivial to derive by simple differentiation, similar to Didier's approach.

Comment: I like your approach the most!

Answer (score 10):

Consider $f(x) = x+\mathrm{e}^{x^2}-\mathrm{e}^x$. Then $f'(x) = 1+ 2x\mathrm{e}^{x^2}-\mathrm{e}^x$ and 
$$f''(x) = 2(1+2x^2)\mathrm{e}^{x^2}-\mathrm{e}^x\ge \mathrm{e}^xg(x),
$$ 
with $g(x)=2\mathrm{e}^{x^2-x}-1$. Since $x^2-x\ge-\frac14$, $g(x)\ge2\mathrm{e}^{-1/4}-1>0$ for every $x$, hence $f''$ is positive everywhere and $f'$ is increasing. Since $f'(0)=0$, $f'(x)<0$ if $x<0$ and $f'(x)>0$ if $x>0$. Thus, the function $x\mapsto f(x)$ is decreasing on $x\le0$ and increasing on $x\ge0$. Since $f(0)=0$, we are done.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:**  Consider the power series of $e^x$ which converges on all of $\mathbb{R}$.  Then $$e^x-x=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$ and $$e^{x^2}=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{3!}+\cdots .$$ For small $x$ the $x^2$ dominates, and for $|x|\geq 1$ the second power series will dominate the first.  (The coefficient of $x^{2n}$ is large enough to cover both coefficients of $x^{2n-1}$ and $x^{2n}$ in the first expansion.)

Comment: but is this rigorous, comparing two infinite sums?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine since these series converge nicely everywhere.

Comment: If I may complete your post, the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the expansion of $\mathrm{e}^{x^2}$ is indeed larger than the sum of the coefficients of $x^{2n−1}$ and $x^{2n}$ in the expansion of $\mathrm{e}^x-x$, hence the conclusion holds for $|x|\ge1$. But this argument cannot work for $|x|<1$. Fortunately, the same coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the expansion of $\mathrm{e}^{x^2}$ is also larger than the sum of the coefficients of $x^{2n+1}$ and $x^{2n}$ in the expansion of $\mathrm{e}^x-x$, hence the conclusion holds for $|x|\le1$ as well.

Comment: @Didier:  Thanks, that is a nice way of doing it!

Comment: "but is this rigorous, comparing two infinite sums?" Yes. Viewing an infinite sum as a *limit* of  a sequence of it's partial sums, this is simply an application of the result that *the pointwise addition of two convergent infinite sequences converges*. For example, if $x_n\to 3$ and $y_n\to 4$ then $x_n+y_n\to 7.$

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f(x) = x+e^{x^2}-e^x$. Then $f'(x) = 1+ 2xe^{x^2}-e^x$. Find the critical points. So the minimum of $f(x)$ is $0$ which implies that $e^x \leq x+e^{x^2}$.

Comment: how did you find the critical points then?