# how to determine delta epsilon figures for an equation involving the constant e

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

For the problem $\lim_{x\to 0} {e^x-1 \over x}=1$,  I need to solve for x in order to solve using the delta epsilon definition. How do I go about solving for x in the equation $f(x)={e^x-1 \over x}$? Thanks.

What I have tried so far:

$${e^x-1\over x}-1 < .1$$
$${e^x-1\over x} < 1.1$$
$$e^x-1<1.1x$$
$$e^x<1+1.1x$$
$$\ln e^x<\ln(1+1.1x)$$
$$x<\ln(1+1.1x)$$

But this is obviously the incorrect way to go about solving for x. Hints are appreciated.

**Edit**: I realize now that I am supposed to be solving this with a calculator, and have not yet learned about the definition of e in limit form. However, I'm not even sure how to do this with a calculator because every epsilon-delta limit I have solved in the past has involved solving for x and forming an epsilon quotient that way.

For $\epsilon$ = .1, how would I do this using a calculator? Or rather, what form do I need to get $f$ in to set it up so I can?

Comment: Do you have to use the delta-epsilon definition? Because this limit can be evaluated nicely just by using the definition of e. If you'd like, I can summarize this in a post below.

Comment: @AlfredYerger I added what I have tried so far, but yes I need to use the delta epsilon definition for given values. In order to find the necessary $\delta$ i need to solve for x, but am not sure how to do it like this. Thanks

Comment: As you are looking for a limit when $x$ goes to zero, you can limit your $\delta$ to any convenient range, and there is no harm if it turns out too small. You are interested in a *bound*, not an exact result

Answer (score 0):

The following is a good approximation, you can find more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781658/the-proof-of-ex-x-ex2/781703#781703).
$$e^{x} - 1 < x + \frac{x^2}{2-x }  = \epsilon $$

So just solve this for $x$ and put the value of $\epsilon$ and get your bounds for $x$.
$$x(2-x) + x^2 - \epsilon(2-x) = 0 \implies x = \frac{2\epsilon}{(2 +\epsilon)} $$

[Putting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*0.1%2F%282%2B0.1%29) $\epsilon = 0.1$ gives you $x=0.095$ [which gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28E%5E%280.095%29%20-%201%29/%280.095%29%20-%201) you $\displaystyle {\frac{e^{0.1}-1}{0.1}} - 1 \approx 0.049 <  0.1 = \epsilon$

Comment: I guess I am supposed to be solving this with a calculator, see my edit

Comment: @ludragon i have edited the answer.