# Proof of the inequality $e^x \leq x+e^{\frac{9}{16}x^2}$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

How can we prove the inequality $e^x \leq x+e^{\frac{9}{16}x^2}$?

Furthermore, if $e^x \leq x+e^{Cx^2}$ holds, what is the smallest $C$?

It is similar to the question [proof of inequality $e^x\le x+e^{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25187/proof-of-inequality-ex-le-xex2), and I have tried all the approaches mentioned in it, but the bound here is sharper, and the problem is more difficult.

For example, we need to prove that $e^{\frac{9}{16}x^2-x}+x e^{-x}\geq 1$, but when I get for $x\geq 0$,
$$
e^{\frac{9}{16}x^2-x}+x e^{-x}\geq 1+\frac{9}{16}x^2-x + x(1-x)=1-\frac{7}{16}x^2,
$$
I can't go ahead any further.

Comment: You can get a lower bound for $C$ if you consider $x\rightarrow 0^+$ for $$\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2} \leq \frac{e^{Cx^2}-1}{x^2}.$$ The Taylor series allows you to evaluate the limits rather quickly.

Comment: Taking logarithm and one can see that the smallest $C$ should be the maximum of $\frac{\log(e^x-x)}{x^2}$, or about $0.5574$. I don't think that it has a closed form, though.

Comment: @JianingSong. I was typing the same !

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to give a proof. This proof is of course not elegant, but it works!

For $x\le 0$, let $g(x) = e^\frac{x^2}{2}-e^x+x$, then $g'(x) = xe^\frac{x^2}{2}-e^x+1$, $g''(x) = (x^2+1)e^\frac{x^2}{2}-e^x\ge (x^2+1)e^\frac{x^2}{2}-1\ge 0$. So $g'(x)$ increases on $(-\infty,0]$, hence $g'(x)\le g'(0)=0$ for all $x\le 0$; $g(x)$ decreases on $(-\infty,0]$, so $g(x)\ge g(0)=0$ for all $x\le 0$. This shows that $e^x\le x+e^\frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x\le 0$.

Now suppose that $x\ge 0$. Note that $e^x\ge 1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ for all odd $n$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so we have
$$e^{\frac{9}{16}x^2-x} + xe^{-x}-1\ge 1+\left(\frac{9}{16}x^2-x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{9}{16}x^2-x\right)^2+\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{9}{16}x^2-x\right)^3+x\left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^5}{120}\right)-1,$$
which simplifies to
$$e^{\frac{9}{16}x^2-x} + xe^{-x}-1\ge \frac{x^2}{122880}(2621x^4 - 14320x^3 + 33520x^2 - 28160x + 7680).$$
It remains to show that $2621x^4 - 14320x^3 + 33520x^2 - 28160x + 7680\ge 0$. Well, there are several ways to prove this, for example by noting that
$$2621x^4 - 14320x^3 + 33520x^2 - 28160x + 7680 = \frac{1}{10484}(5242x^2-14320x+7049)^2 + \frac{3}{15826376437}(6038297x-3889420)^2 + \frac{1763413283}{24153188}.$$